# Why did my loop stop iterating?

Tags: python

```
#newlist to add values to 
newlist = []
# iterate through characters in mystring  
for i in (mystring):
# if a letter, append letter to newlist
    if i.isalpha():
        newlist.append(i)
#if '[', sets open_bracket_index to the index of the bracket
    if i == '[':
        open_bracket_index = mystring.index(i)
#if ']', sets close to the index of the bracket
    if i == ']':
        close_bracket_index = mystring.index(i)
# sets the index points of newlist to join the elements 
newlist[open_bracket_index:close_bracket_index-1] = [''.join(newlist[open_bracket_index:close_bracket_index-1])]
```

why doesn't the loop continue and manipulate the list as it did for the first combined element?

Comment: (1) `mystring.index(i)` always finds the first appearance of letter `i` (2) The last line isn't iterated so the join only happens once (for first brackets).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression to find groups of characters in brackets or just single characters.  The regular expression will return tuples of matches - a match for each side of the regex 'or' (`|`).  For each tuple, only one of the strings will be filled, the other will be an empty string (hence the `join`)

```
import re

mystring = 'AC[BC]D[ABD]'
[''.join(x) for x in re.findall(r'\[(\w+)\]|(\w)', mystring)]
# returns:
['A', 'C', 'BC', 'D', 'ABD']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`:

```
import re
mystring = 'AC[BC]D[ABD]'
final_data = re.findall('(?<=\[)\w+(?=\])|\w', mystring)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C', 'BC', 'D', 'ABD']
```