# How can I loop through a string and print certain items?

Tags: python, loops

```
lst = 'AB[CD]EF[GH]'
```

Output: ['A','B','CD','E','F','GH']

This is what I've tried but it's not working...

```
while(index < len(my_string)):
 curr_char = my_string[index]
 if(curr_char == '['):
      while(curr_char != ']'):
           multi = my_string[index + 1]
           index += 1
lst += multi
```

Can anybody please help? Without importing Regex or whatever. I wanna do this without using it.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: there's clearly an infinite loop here. you need a state machine, and you need to increment the index no matter what. reopening

Comment: you should edit to explain why it's not working, though

Comment: the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169994/why-did-my-loop-stop-iterating do the job, but OP question is different: no regex allowed to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

The problems with the original code seemed to be:

1) lst, index and multi are not initialised

2) the loop is infinite because the loop variable (index) isn't incremented on each iteration.

3) the close bracket needs to be skipped when detected to avoid including it in the final list

This code is an example of how to fix those issues:

```
def getList(s):
    outList=[]
    lIndex=0
    while lIndex < len(s):
        if s[lIndex] == "[":
            letters=""
            lIndex+=1
            while s[lIndex] != "]":
                letters+=s[lIndex]
                lIndex+=1
            outList.append(letters)
        else:
            outList.append(s[lIndex])
        lIndex+=1
    return outList

print(getList('AB[CD]EF[GH]'))
```

Comment: dumping code as an answer isn't good enough. You need to explain why OP code wasn't working and how your code works

Comment: thank you for the feedback - the problems with the OP code were: 1) lst, index and multi are not initialised 2) the loop is infinite because the loop variable (index) isn't incremented on each iteration. 3) the close bracket needs to be skipped when detected to avoid including it in the final list

Comment: sounds good, [edit] your answer. Comments are not designed for that.

Comment: thank you, still new here, learning how to use this effectively. my original answer has been edited now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use

```
lst += multi
```

because you can't concatenate a string with a list.

Moreover, your code enters an infinite loop, because you aren't updating the `curr_char` variable inside the inner loop, so the condition will always be `True`.

Also, you are not handling the case when `curr_char != '['`. And more errors there are.

You can use this code which fixes the above errors while using the same basic logic as your code:

```
index = 0
multi = ""
res = []
my_str = 'AB[CD]EF[GH]'

while (index < len(my_str)):
    curr_char = my_str[index]
    if curr_char == '[':
        multi += curr_char
        while curr_char != ']':
            index += 1
            curr_char = my_str[index]
            multi += curr_char
        res.append(multi)
        multi = ""
    else:
        res.append(curr_char)
    index += 1

print(res)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', '[CD]', 'E', 'F', '[GH]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code snippet.

```
my_string = 'AB[CD]EF[GH]'

lst = []
ind = 0
n = len(my_string)

while (ind < n):
    if my_string[ind] == '[':
        # if '[' is found, look for the next ']' but ind should not exceed n.
        # Your code does not do a ind < n check. It may enter an infinite loop.
        ind += 1 # this is done to skip the '[' in result list
        temp = '' # create a temporary string to store chars inside '[]'
        while ind < n and my_string[ind] != ']':
            temp = temp + my_string[ind]
            ind+=1
        lst.append(temp) # add this temp string to list
        ind += 1 # do this to skip the ending ']'.
    else:
        # If its not '[', simply append char to list.
        lst.append(my_string[ind])
        ind += 1

print(lst)
```